# 4GL Progress/openedge thousand separates

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to do thousand separates for this value `100000000`. How can i do it in progress.

**Sample Code**

```
DEFINE VARIABLE mAmount AS DECIMAL  NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN mAmount = 100000000.
MESSAGE mAmount VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK TITLE "Amount".
```

Answer (score 6):

The `MESSAGE` statement does not format the variable. You have to convert it to a `STRING` and provide the correct format.

```
MESSAGE STRING(mAmount, "zzz,zzz,zz9") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK TITLE "Amount".
```

The `DISPLAY` statement does use the format which is defined in the `DEFINE VARIABLE` statement, or you can use a custom format with the `FORMAT` statement. Example:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE mAmount AS DECIMAL FORMAT "zzz,zzz,zz9" NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN mAmount = 100000000.
DISPLAY mAmount WITH FRAME a.
DISPLAY mAmount FORMAT "zzzzzz,zz9" WITH FRAME b.
```

Comment: +1 for Arno's answer. Especially using the format in the variable definition, which will give you the display mask you want anytime the variable is displayed, no matter the output.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use:
">>>,>>>,>>9" in format.